# How to match exactly a word with a colon before it, ignoring case?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I need to build an SQL prepare application that should replace the parameters inside the script.

Each parameter should be matched exactly, but ignoring the case.

What I'm trying to achieve is, to pass the Name of the parameter intended to be replaced preceded with the colon character, but my regex does not match.

I'm using:

```
'\b' + _Parameter + '\b';
```

The actual value of the `_Parameter` variable is `':value'` without the quotes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's much safer to use query parameters rather than replace the text ... is there a reason why you don't want to do that?  For example in FireDac you can set query or command parameters as TFDParam objects and find them by name or position.  Using parameters you don't have to worry that the text you are inserting into the query is valid SQL, and it also safeguards against  SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you for replying. Yes, I’m aware of that. I don’t use declared fields and the scripts are put together at runtime. Just prefere to do it that way, for this application specifically. Security is not a matter.

Comment: Use a tool (online or local) to debug your regexes. Drop the `\:` from the first string literal as it is in the wrong place (before a word ending) and a semicolon is already in the variable value.

Comment: Hi Brian: /bText/b bypass the colon. I already tested it. But I must drop /: since it’s not doing anything. The problem is how to build the expression in a way that match the text with the preciding colon

Answer (score 0):

Done!

```
(\:value\b)
```

assuming that I wish to match the text ":value"